# Make a non editable cell editable while adding new row

Tags: slickgrid

In my slick grid I have a non editable column, can we make the cell editable while adding the new row.

I have looked into onBeforeEditCell event but that's kinda helpful when making a editable cell non editable.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that determines whether a column can be edited is whether it has `col.editor` defined.

You could alter this using something like `grid.getColumns()[3].editor = Slick.Editors.Text` (set to `null` or `undefined` to remove).

You'd have to detect the moving to a new row to decide how to set the editor. The `onActiveCellChanged` event seems like the best place to do this, but note that internally, editing mode decisions are already made by the time this event is called - see the internal function `setActiveCellInternal`. You might be best off declaring a new event and putting it earlier in that function, or moving the existing one up.

This is not a use case I think would be very widespread.

Note [my repo](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) is worth trying for the many updates and bug fixes it has over the now unmaintained original MLeibman repo.